# Correct way for responding resources from http server

Tags: java, html, css, resources, httpserver

I have this index.html page:

```
   <html>
    <head>
     <title>My Site</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/example.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
     <h2>Hello world</h2>
     <p>Image:</p>
     <img src="someimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142">
    </body>
   </html>
```

And I wrote a simple java Http server. This server handles the request, load `index.html` from the resources folder and responses to the client(browser). The client sees `index.html` but without resources(images, CSS, js). Because browser after loading `index.html` tries to load all resources included to this page. But resources in the server. I Wrote a new handler with path like `/assets/` and tried to replace all links to resources in `index.html` like this:

```
<img src="someimage.jpg" width="104" height="142">
```

to

```
<img src="/assets/someimage.jpg" width="104" height="142">
```

After that in `/assets/` handler, I cut the first part of URI (`/assets/`) and try load from resources second part of URI(`someimage.jpg`);

It works, but I can not load CSS. Because I replace `pageAsString.replace("src=\"", "/assets/");`
but CSS in `href="css/example.css"`

Maybe I doing something wrong and this approach is bad? How can I return index.html to the client and give the ability for loading resources from the server?

Comment: which kind of server do you use?

Comment: @Den Doeson https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Made quick single-class project based on your question. Made IMG and SCRIPT tags work:

```
package test.server;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.URI;

public class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException, IOException {
        InputStream is = t.getRequestBody();

        InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String str;
        while((str = reader.readLine())!= null){
            sb.append(str);
        }

        String response = "<html>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<head>\n" +
                "    <title>My Site</title>\n" +
                "    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/example.css\" />\n" +
                "</head>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "    <h2>Hello world</h2>\n" +
                "    <p>Image:</p>\n" +
                "    <img src=\"/assets/cat.jpg\" alt=\"W3Schools.com\" width=\"104\" height=\"142\">\n" +
                "    <script src=\"/assets/alert.js\"></script>\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "</html>";

        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        InetSocketAddress cd = new InetSocketAddress(8080);
        HttpServer server = null;
        try {
            server = HttpServer.create(cd, 8080);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        server.createContext("/main", new MyHandler());

        server.createContext("/assets/", new HttpHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
                String root = "!!! YOUR SITE ROOT IN FILE SYSTEM !!!";
                URI uri = httpExchange.getRequestURI();
                File file = new File(root + uri.getPath()).getCanonicalFile();
                if (!file.getPath().startsWith(root)) {
                    // Suspected path traversal attack: reject with 403 error.
                    String response = "403 (Forbidden)\n";
                    httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(403, response.length());
                    OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
                    os.write(response.getBytes());
                    os.close();
                } else if (!file.isFile()) {
                    // Object does not exist or is not a file: reject with 404 error.
                    String response = "404 (Not Found)\n";
                    httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(404, response.length());
                    OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
                    os.write(response.getBytes());
                    os.close();
                } else {
                    // Object exists and is a file: accept with response code 200.
                    httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
                    OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
                    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
                    final byte[] buffer = new byte[0x10000];
                    int count = 0;
                    while ((count = fs.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                        os.write(buffer,0,count);
                    }
                    fs.close();
                    os.close();
                }
            }
        });
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
    }
}
```

alert.js can be like

```
alert("I'm from inner file!");
console.log("I'm from inner file!");
```

image is any jpg image

project structure (for us there are src and assets folders):

[image]

Run main method and go to **http://localhost:8080/main**

Everything should work correct.

**NOTE** One thing in java code you should change - path in your file system.

**PS** based on http://www.microhowto.info/howto/serve_web_pages_using_an_embedded_http_server_in_java.html